# Finding a Closed Form for Recursive Function

Tags: recursion

Consider the following recurrence relation.

```
 T(n) = 5 if n <= 2
 T(n-1) + n otherwise
```

Closed form solution for `T(n)` is

I got solution as `n(n+1)/2 + 7` for all the values. But in my university exam they gave the solution `n(n+1)/2 + 2`. However this solution doesn't terminate at `5` for values `n<2`. Can some body please explain ?

Comment: n(n+1)/2 + 2 is not a solution of the equations given. What's to explain?

Comment: @PaulHankin tested it, `n(n+1)/2 + 2` works for all values in the range 2-50. Doesn't work for `n=1`, but apart from that this is definitely the solution.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a pure math question, not a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's solve it; first let's expand in telescopic sums:

```
 T(k)     = T(k)
 T(k + 1) = T(k) + k + 1
 T(k + 2) = T(k + 1) + k + 2 = T(k) + k + 1 + k + 2
 ...
 T(k + m) = T(k) + k + 1 + k + 2 + ... + k + m =
          = T(k) + mk + 1 + 2 + ... + m =
          = T(k) + mk + (1 + m) * m / 2
 ...
```

Now we have

```
 T(k + m) = T(k) + mk + (1 + m) * m / 2
```

Let `k = 2`:

```
 T(m + 2) = T(2) + 2m + (1 + m) * m / 2 = 5 + 2m + (1 + m) * m / 2
```

Finally, let `m + 2 = n` or `m = n - 2`:

```
 T(n) = 5 + 2 * (n - 2) + (n - 1) * (n - 2) / 2 = n * (n + 1) / 2 + 2
```

We have

```
 T(n) = n * (n + 1) / 2 + 2 when n  > 2
 T(n) = 5                   when n <= 2
```

Comment: When you consider a closed form solution, Can we add exceptions that the T(n) doesn't valid for n<2. The function T(n) should terminate at all the values without any exceptions..Isn't it what the closed form means..? If we add exceptions that for n<2, T(n) will give different result...then how can we call it a closed form solution?

Comment: @Y.Surya Narayana: as you can see we begin from *expanding* the serie: `T(k) = ... T(k  + 1) = ...` that's why the soultion is true starting from some `k`. Then we explictly put `k = 2` which is the minimum index we used, so the solution is true for the indexes more than `2`: `T(n) = n * (n + 1) / 2 + 2 when n  > 2`: we haven't compute `T(2)` but have taken it.

Answer (score 0):

As a simple non-rigorous reasoning exercise, we known that `T(n) = T(n-1) + n` yields the sum of the first `n` numbers: `S(n) = n * (n + 1) / 2`

Now, when `n=2`, `S(2) = 3`, so the value of `5` is actually an increment by `5 - S(2) = 2`. So we could say:

```
T(n) = S(n) + (5 - S(2)) for n >=2
```

or

```
T(n) = S(n) + 2 for n >= 2
T(n) = 5 for n <= 2
```

Note that at `n=2`, the two relations are identical.